# Using AesCryptoServiceProvider in VB.NET

Tags: java, vb.net, aes, encryption

My problem is actually a bit more complicated than just how to use AES in VB.NET, since what I'm really trying to do is use AES in VB.NET from within a Java application across JACOB.  But for now, what I need to focus on is the AES implementation itself.

Here's my encryption code

```
Public Function EncryptAES(ByVal toEncrypt As String, ByVal key As String) As Byte()
    Dim keyArray = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim toEncryptArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(toEncrypt)

    Dim aes = New AesCryptoServiceProvider
    aes.Key = keyArray
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
    Dim encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor()

    Dim encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length)
    aes.Clear()

    Return encrypted
End Function
```

Once back in the Java code, I turn the byte array into a hexadecimal String.

Now, to reverse the process, here's my decryption code

```
Public Function DecryptAES(ByVal toDecrypt As String, ByVal key As String) As Byte()
    Dim keyArray = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt)

    Dim aes = New AesCryptoServiceProvider
    aes.Key = keyArray
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
    Dim decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor()

    Dim decrypted = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length)
    aes.Clear()
    Return decrypted
End Function
```

When I run the decryption code, I get the following error message

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.

Comment: Have you tried saving your encrypted data somewhere, and then comparing that saved data byte-for-byte to a call to your decrypt function after passing it through java?

Comment: Also: what version of vb.net/visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 Pro

I can't do the test you're suggesting because I'm not getting to the point where I have a return value from decrypt to test.  The error is being thrown by my VB decryption function.

Comment: Can you round-trip a piece of data without sending it to Java?   Ie. DecryptAES(EncryptAES("text", "key"), "key")

Comment: Yep, sure can Jeremy.  Actually, I've improved the code some.  I'll be posting a solution soon.

Comment: Curious - why use JACOB?  Why not just use the AES cipher that is part of the JRE?

Comment: Note that ECB is rarely a good mode. So please don't copy&paste this code if you want to encrypt something in VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there were a couple of things wrong with my original code.

For one, no debugging.  I had to add an internal test to verify that my code could encrypt and decrypt before wrapping it in Java.  That was silly of me.

Two: the TransformFinalBlock method of both the encryptor and decryptor objects doesn't seem to perform as advertised.

Enough talk.  Here's the code

```
Public Function EncryptAES(ByVal clearText As String, ByVal key As String) As String

    ' prepare input
    Dim keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim sourceBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)

    ' prepare encryption provider
    Dim aes = New AesCryptoServiceProvider
    aes.Key = keyBytes
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
    Dim encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor()

    Dim ms = New MemoryStream
    Dim cs = New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(sourceBytes, 0, sourceBytes.Length)
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())

    'Dim decrypted = DecryptAES(encrypted, key)
    'If Not EventLog.SourceExists("CryptoBridge") Then
    '   EventLog.CreateEventSource("CryptoBridge", "CryptoBridge")
    'End If
    'Dim log As New EventLog
    'log.Source = "CryptoBridge"
    'log.WriteEntry(clearText & ":" & decrypted)

    aes.Clear()
    cs.Dispose()
    ms.Dispose()

    Return encrypted
End Function

Public Function DecryptAES(ByVal base64Cipher As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key)
    Dim cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Cipher)

    ' prepare decryption provider
    Dim aes = New AesCryptoServiceProvider
    aes.Key = keyBytes
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
    Dim decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor()

    Dim ms = New MemoryStream(cipherBytes)
    Dim cs = New CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

    Dim decryptedBytes As Byte()
    ReDim decryptedBytes(cipherBytes.Length)

    Dim readByteCount = cs.Read(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length)
    Dim decrypted = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedBytes, 0, readByteCount)

    aes.Clear()
    cs.Dispose()
    ms.Dispose()

    Return decrypted
End Function
```

Next, I'll be modifying this code to bump up the AES algorithm to 256-bit and CBC cipher mode, which requires an initial vector (IV) value.  This adds a level of complexity to the implementation that I wasn't ready to add until the rest worked 100% of the time.

Thanks to all those who commented on my issue.

Comment: Curious - why would you not just use the AES Ciphers that are included in Java? as opposed to going across JACOB?